# Can all for loops in python be converted into list comprehension equivalent?

Tags: python, for-loop, list-comprehension

List comprehension looks more pythonic to me. It is also faster than for loops.

Are ALL for loops in python convertible into list comprehension?

I am using python 3.7

*EDIT: It seems like it's a bad idea to use list comprehension when the for loop is long and complicated. It makes the code much less readable.*

Comment: List comprehensions are not meant to be jack of all trades. There are many situations, especially when requiring side effects, where they are pretty badly suited readability-wise, whereas plain old `for` loops are much more idiomatic. _cf_ [PEP20 - Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

Comment: List comprehensions are not for *speed*, in the cases where they are faster it is marginal, they are for readability, for expressing mapping/filtering operations that result in lists. It is *not* pythonic to try to make a list comprehension out of every for-loop.

Comment: There are for loops that can not be converted into list comprehensions. For example if they contain certain reserved keywords (`class`, `def`, `try`, `except`…).

Comment: @KlausD. well, if you can wrap it in a function, you can do it, without that though, everything that isn't an expression (all compound statements, etc) cannot go into a list-comprehension, at least not *directly*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, sort of.

You can convert nested for loops to list comprehensions, and even use variable assignment with `:=`.

It is true that list comprehensions are slighly faster than for loops, but the difference is so negligible that it is not worth trying to cram a complicated loop into a list comprehension.

Comment: I did some reading. It seems list comprehension is suited for simple for loops. Listcomp is less readable to me. Nested for loop list comp will be a nightmare to read.

Comment: Yep, I would not try to turn a complicated for loop into a list comprehension. It can get quite nasty.